# Olympiad question: How many positive integers which are $\leq2013$ such that $3$ or $5$ divide the number.

Tags: number-theory

How many positive integers which are $\leq2013$ such that $3$ or $5$ divide the number.

Comment: you are rigth but I don't have any idea how to solve it so forgive me

Comment: OK, do you know how to count how many multiples of $5$ there are, between $1$ and $2013$? If not, try with simpler numbers: Try to count the number of multiples of $2$, and then $3$, between $1$ and $20$ (you can count these by hand, and make a guess at some kind of formula)

Comment: I don't understand.  In a comment above, you say "*you are rigth but I don't have any idea how to solve it so forgive me*" and in a comment under the answer of barak manos, you say "*Well I solved it like this but i thought this is to easy question for math olympiad.Thanks*".  How can you have no idea how to solve it but then find it too easy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *inclusion/exclusion* principle:

- Include the amount of numbers that are divisible by $3$, which is $\lfloor\frac{2013}{3}\rfloor=671$
- Include the amount of numbers that are divisible by $5$, which is $\lfloor\frac{2013}{5}\rfloor=402$
- Exclude the amount of numbers that are divisible by $3$ **and** $5$, which is $\lfloor\frac{2013}{3\cdot5}\rfloor=134$

Hence the amount of numbers that are divisible by $3$ **or** $5$ is $671+402-134=939$.

Comment: Well I solved it like this but i thought this is to easy question for math olympiad.Thanks

Comment: @eee Your welcome. I don't know what *math olympiad* is, but perhaps it targets a certain (possibly younger) crowd or something like that. In any case, I don't think that a solution to **any question whatsoever** should forcefully be made complex in order to "match" the context in which the question is asked (a contest or whatever that is). If you have a simple straightforward solution at hand, why not using it?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: All $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, $n\geq8$ can be written as $n=3a+5b$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$.

$\textit{Proof}$.   $\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}$, $n\equiv0(\text{mod 3}),\;n\equiv1(\text{mod 3}),\;\text{or}\;n\equiv2(\text{mod 3})$. We consider these 3 cases.

1) $n\equiv0(\text{mod 3})$ then $n=3k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Hence, $3k=3a+5b=3(k)+5(0),$ $a=k,\;b=0$.

2). $n\equiv1(\text{mod 3})$ then $n=3k+1$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ Hence, $3k+1=3(k-3)+10=3(k-3)+5(2)$ so $a=k-3,\;b=2$.

3). $n\equiv2(\text{mod 3})$ then $n=3k+2$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Hence $3k+2=3(k-1)+5$ so $a=k-1,\;b=1$. 
$\square$